# Nginx+uwsgi. Works fine on localhost, but not on remote machine. WHY

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, deployment, uwsgi

Case:
In docker network is created with:

```sh
docker network create --attachable --subnet 1.1.1.0/29 some-network
```

1st container is Flask+uwsgi and is launched like:

```sh
docker run -d --rm --net some-network --ip 1.1.1.4 \
-p 8080:8080 --name my-flask my-flask-image
```

uwsgi ini looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:app
master = true
processes = 2
socket = :8080
```

2nd container is nginx and is launched like:

```sh
docker run -d --rm --net some-network --ip 1.1.1.2 \
-p 80:80 --name my-nginx my-nginx-image
```

config only adds next server config

```
upstream app_dev {
    server  1.1.1.4:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name develop.localhost;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass app_dev;
    }
}
```

I run containers and i access develop.localhost without any problem.

However when I run containers on remote machine with domain_name(surely with added A record I can access server through ssh by domain_name) I can't access not nginx, not uwsgi: docker logs  show no requests.

I can only access(from browser) by ip address but then nginx respond with 502.
nginx config slightly changes from local only ssl stuff(and ssl) with domain_name added

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name develop.domainname.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/CERTIFICATE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/KEY.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass app_dev;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to diagnose problem - I don't understand why logs are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i was typing this case i realized problem.
I did not exposed 443 port for nginx.
I added port to run command and it kinda works.

```sh
-p 443:443
```

"kinda" - because after that firefox started screaming that i have bad ssl certificate. Apparently godaddy gave me ssl-certificate for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and domain.com, but not for wildcard domains.